# Copy files and create symlink from a shared volume on Docker on container start

Tags: docker, dockerfile, supervisord

I have a container mounting a shared volume on run, and I need to copy some files from the location where this volume mounts to another and create a symlink.

I tried several ways, and lastly I was using supervisor. So I created I simple bash script which cp and ln what I need from where the volume is mounted on the docker container to my final destination inside the docker container. But supervisor fails.

This is my supervisor conf file:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:nonversioned]
command=/deploy.sh
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
exitcodes=1
```

This is an example of what it has my deploy.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Copy config files
cp -f /efs/deploys/wp-config.php /var/www/html

# Softlink to uploads
ln -s /efs/deploys/uploads /var/www/html/assets/uploads
```

In my Dockerfile also tried several things of launching supervisor. Lastly I was trying with:

```
CMD ["supervisord -n"]
```

But it says that supervisord is not in the path

And I am starting my container with:

```
docker run -d 
        -v /home/user/my_efs:/efs \
        mytest/testing
```

Comment: Yep, that was it, with the full path and separated. Thanks

Comment: Will post that as an answer instead actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the command and arguments separately, e.g.

```
CMD ["supervisord", "-n"]
```

It's possible that it still won't find `supervisord` in the path. In that case, just specify the full path:

```
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-n"]
```